# SOA suite 11 installation

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel

I have a short question.
After I install Oracle SOA Suite, the managed servers soa_server1 and bam_server1 are created and configured automatically ( the only thing I need is to start them ?), or I need to do this by myself ( create and configure)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the SOA Suite, you need to create and configure a domain. 
You define managed servers that you need in your domain.
11g links: 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/install.1111/e13925/configure.htm#INSOA218

https://udayarocks.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/how-to-create-a-domain-with-soa-managed-server-in-weblogic-server-11g/

(If you used the SOA Quickstart installer for 12c for development purposes, an "integrated domain" might get created automatically when you run some code from within JDeveloper - this integrated domain typically has everything (soa/osb/bam) on a single server and is suitable only for development)